# Problema con Cookies entre aplicaciones web Genexus

Tags: genexus, cookies

Estoy teniendo un problema con Gx17U8 al generar cookies para la ruta de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es molesto ya que al entrar en otras aplicaciones del mismo dominio, ejemplo: sub.mydominio.com/app1, generada con Gx17U8, y sub.mydominio.com/app2, generada con Gx16U11; se genera un inconveniente de cookies y me tira un error 500 Invalid Key, por lo que debo borrar las cookies y recargar la aplicación.

Esto con Gx16U11 no pasaba, por tanto me gustaría saber si alguien encontró una solución.

Tengo entendido que en Gx17 se agregó una nueva propiedad a nivel de Environment.
Esta es la de Samesite cookie attribute y que para mantener la compatibilidad con las versiones anteriores esta se setea por defecto en el valor Lax.

Ya he probado realizando combinaciones de esta propiedad junto con variaciones en las demás que acompañan a la seguridad web (Encrypt URL parameters y Protocol specification) y no consigo que las cookies se generen solamente para la aplicación.

Algunas consideraciones son: Las aplicaciones corren bajo un Apache Server y no se utiliza un balanceador de carga

Comment: Este problema quedó solucionado en el próximo Upgrade de V17 #U10.

Answer (score 1):

Las cookies se están generando por "host" y no por "webapp".
Si la clave de encriptación (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36909,Application%20Encryption%20Key%20property) es la misma para todas las webapps no hay problema, pero si cada webapp tiene una clave diferente entonces la segunda aplicación no sabe desencriptar el valor.

Para resolverlo lo que puedes hacer es usar "Site Key" en la encriptación y asegurarte que las webapps tenga la misma "application.key".

Más información: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=51131

Nota: en el canal beta está corregido el problema (se incluye la ruta) https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/betatesters?data=V17BETA